# Add active class to a clicked wordpress tab?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add an "active" class to the clicked tab in a WordPress cloud tag.

This is the way I create the tag cloud:

```
 <?php
   $args = array(
     "hide_empty" => false
   );

   if ( function_exists('wp_tag_cloud') ) :
 ?>
    <div class="span4 grey sidebar">
        <div class="padded news-tag">
            <p class="prio-3">Show more about</p>
            <?php wp_tag_cloud($args); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
   endif;
?>
```

And this is the HTML generated:

```
<body class="archive tag tag-testing tag-62">
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4 grey sidebar">
                <div class="padded news-tag">
                    <p class="prio-3">Show more about</p>
                    <a href="link" class="tag-link-65" title="testing" style="font-size: 22pt;">testing</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And I would like to be able to access the clicked tag and add an "active" class with jQuery using something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function(jQuery){
        jQuery( '.sidebar .news-tag a' ).click(function(e){
            var element = $(this);
            if( element.hasClass('active') ) {
                return false;
            }
            else {   
                element.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }(jQuery))
</script>
```

Does anyone knows the proper way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I'm going to post it here just in case anyone need it.

First I check the clicked tag by checking the URL parameters:

```
<?php
    global $wp;
    $current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
    $url_tag_php = substr( $current_url, strrpos( $current_url, '=' )+1 );
?>
```

Now that we know the name of the tag is possible to work with jQuery to add the 'active' class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
    jQuery().ready(function() {
      jQuery(".news-tag a").each(function() {
        addActiveClassTag(this);
        return true;
      });
    });

    function addActiveClassTag(thisObj) {
      var pageTag = jQuery(thisObj).text().toLowerCase();
      var url_tag = '<?php echo $url_tag_php ?>';
      if ( pageTag == url_tag ) {
        jQuery(thisObj).addClass('active');
      }
      return true;
    }
</script>
```

I hope this will help you as much as it helped me. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Do like this:

```
jQuery( '.sidebar .news-tag a' ).click(function(e){

  jQuery( '.sidebar .news-tag a' ).removeClass("active"); // remove class from other tab

  jQuery(this).addClass("active"); // set class to current clicked tab

});
```

Comment: cant get any better than that

Comment: i used to do this way, and i think its not so expensive one

Comment: then show your complete html, and also check console for any errors

Comment: The HTML is now on top, and I don't get any error in the console.

Comment: @Alberto: could you update your click handler with latest change in your question above, so that we can see if you are missing something there

Comment: where is anchor tag inside .news-tag in html @Alberto??

Comment: HTML generated is in the top

Comment: Maybe anything work because the click event loads a new page instead of using ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
    $( '.sidebar .news-tag a' ).click(function(e){
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}); // <------update to this.
</script>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work either. I don't know what else to try

Comment: @Alberto would you post generated html instead?

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the 'active' class from any elements on the screen. Then, add the class to the clicked element.

```
  jQuery( document ).ready(function(jQuery){
        jQuery( '.sidebar .news-tag a' ).click(function(e){

            var element = $(this);

            if($('.active').length>0){ //if there is an active element...

              $('.active').removeClass('active'); //remove the class from it.
              //note that the if is optional, but treating this exception might
              // be useful in the future.
            }

            element.addClass('active'); //now, add the class to this element

        });
    });
```

Comment: Not working in my project. Any error in the console.